# ¿como esperar a que terminen 2 peticiones AJAX antes de hacer un procesamiento con la respuesta de las 2? Sin JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy realizando varias pruebas para conseguir juntar la informacion de dos peticiones AJAX (Sin JQuery) distintas ( por tanto con sus diferentes tiempos etc... ) pero no consigo "sacar" la informacion de la funcion que procesa la respuesta AJAX .

Pongo un ejemplo :

Peticion AJAX normal a un TXT ( sin jquery)

```
function cargar_txt(){
  //Inicializa_xhr Obtener la instancia del objeto XMLHttpRequest creando una variable
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
 peticion_http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
 peticion_http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if(peticion_http) 
{
    peticion_http.onreadystatechange = procesar_txt;
    peticion_http.open("POST", "ruta_de_mi_archivo", true);
    peticion_http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    peticion_http.send("");
}
```

Funcion que lee lo recibido :

```
function procesar_txt() {

if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) 
{
    if(peticion_http.status == 200) 
    {
        var cadena = peticion_http.responseText;
        var secundario = cadena.split(";");

        return secundario ; 
    }
 }
}
```

Las dos peticiones son bastante parecidad , el problema esta al intentar "extraer" la información del entorno local de la funcion , no hay manera , ni con CallBacks ni con promesas consigo poder utilizar la informacion fuera de la funcion , el valor siempre es "undefined" .

¿Alguna solucion?
Muchas gracias.

PD: A peticion de Trauma en este caso (partiendo del codigo anterior sin return , igualando a la variable global ) lo intento hacer con promesas y naranjas de la china .

```
var gloabl = [];
var global1 = [];

cargar_txt();
var procesar_txt = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('Informacion primer AJAX:'+global[0]);
    }, 5000);
  })
}
cargar_txt_segundo();
var procesar_txt_segundo = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('Informacion segundo AJAX:'+global1[0]);
    }, 2000);
  })
}

Promise.all([procesar_txt(global), procesar_txt_segundo(global1)])
  .then((result) => {
    alert(result.join(','));
    console.log();
  })
  .catch(e => alert(`Error capturado:  ${e}`));
```

Comment: Dices que has utilizado *callbacks* y *promesas*; de la forma que muestras, es **la única** en lo que no puedes conseguirlo. ¿ Puedes poner el código que has usado en el resto de tus pruebas ?

Comment: @Trauma Lo edito

Answer (score 1):

Puedes primero crear una función genérica que *convierta* una llamada AJAX en una promesa:

```
function requestPromesa (method, url, body) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject({
          status: xhr.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      reject({
        status: xhr.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };
    xhr.send(body);
  });
}
```

Y usarla para tus dos llamadas, uniéndolas con `Promise.all`:

```
const p1 = requestPromesa('POST','url_cualquiera');
const p2 = requestPromesa('GET','otra_url_cualquiera');
Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(function (respuestas) {
  const respuesta1 = respuestas[0];
  const respuesta2 = respuestas[1];
  ...
}).catch(function (statusError) { ... });
```